# How can I call a routine automatically when the run ends in specman?

Tags: specman, atexit

Is there any way to specify that a function should be called when a test ends in Specman?

I'm looking for something similar to C's atexit().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haven't tried my self, but you should probably have a look at the `finalize()` or `quit()` methods which are defined for `any_struct`. You could try to extend it for `sys`.

```
extend sys {
    finalize() is also {
        // ...
    };
};
```

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Looking at specman's help, it looks like `finalize()` is what I'm looking for.  `quit()` will simply exit the test.  Thanks!